# Active Admin: How to customize labels for select filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, activeadmin

This seems like it should be fairly simple, buy I haven't been able to find any documentation on the subject.

I have the following filter:

```
filter :archived, as: :select
```

...which gives me a working filter in the form of a select box with options "Any", "Yes", and "No".

My question is: How do I customize these labels such that the functionality remains the same, but the labels are instead "All", "Live", and "Archived"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The quick and easy:

```
filter :archived, as: :select, collection: [['Live', 'true'], ['Archived', 'false']]
```

However, that won't give you a way to customize the "All" option without changing I18n.

UPDATED: Here's another option:

```
# Somewhere, in an initializer or just straight in your activeadmin file:
class ActiveAdmin::Inputs::FilterIsArchivedInput < ActiveAdmin::Inputs::FilterSelectInput
  def input_options
    super.merge include_blank: 'All'
  end

  def collection
    [ ['Live', 'true'], ['Archived', 'false'] ]
  end
end

# In activeadmin
filter :archived, as: :is_archived
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I need custom select in index filters and form inputs, so I have found a similar solution:
In app/inputs (like suggest formtastic) I create two clases:

In app/inputs/country_select_input.rb:

```
class CountrySelectInput < Formtastic::Inputs::SelectInput

  def collection
    I18nCountrySelect::Countries::COUNTRY_CODES.map { |country_code|
      translation = I18n.t(country_code, scope: :countries, default: 'missing')
      translation == 'missing' ? nil : [translation, country_code]
    }.compact.sort
  end

end
```

In app/inputs/filter_country_select_input.rb:

```
class FilterCountrySelectInput < ActiveAdmin::Inputs::FilterSelectInput

  def collection
    I18nCountrySelect::Countries::COUNTRY_CODES.map { |country_code|
      translation = I18n.t(country_code, scope: :countries, default: 'missing')
      translation == 'missing' ? nil : [translation, country_code]
    }.compact.sort
  end

end
```

And in my app/admin/city.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register City do

  index do
    column :name
    column :country_code, sortable: :country_code do |city|
      I18n.t(city.country_code, scope: :countries)
    end
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    default_actions
  end

  filter :name
  filter :country_code, as: :country_select
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :country_code, as: :country_select
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

As you can see, ActiveAdmin look for Filter[:your_custom_name:]Input  and [:your_custom_name:]Input in different context, index filters or form inputs. So, you can create this clases extending of ActiveAdmin::Inputs::FilterSelectInput or Formtastic::Inputs::SelectInput and customize your logic.

It works for me, I hope you can find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack that works... without requiring you to write new inputs controls!

```
filter :archived, as: :select, collection: -> { [['Yes', 'true'], ['No', 'false']] }

index do
  script do
    """
      $(function () {
        $('select[name=\"q[archived]\"] option[value=\"\"]').text('All');
      });
    """.html_safe
  end
  column :id
  column :something
end
```

It's not "clean" nor "elegant", but works well enough :)